# How does C++ program know where to find a function just from the declaration?

Tags: c++

From what I have been seeing from `C++` code examples, if I have two files `Log.cpp` and `Math.cpp`

in `Math.cpp` we have,

```
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message);

static int multiply(int a, int b){
    Log("Multiply");
    return a * b;
}
```

in `Log.cpp` we simply print the text that was given to us. However unlike most programming languages that I use we do not directly import the method from a specific module or file, we simply declare it in `C++`. For example in Python it would be `from x import y`, which meant that we could have multiple definitions of `y` but depending from where we imported it from, depended in which implementation was used. How would this works in `C++` if I had multiple definitions of `Log`, how would it know which one to use?

Comment: Handy reading: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work) You're mostly interested in the linking stage.

Comment: It doesn't. C++ does not work this way. If your intent is to learn C++, the most important thing to learn is to forget all other languages. C++ is not Java. C++ is not Python. C++ works in fundamentally different ways than other programming languages.

Comment: The way C++ handles multiple functions with the same name is to make sure they are declared in different namespaces.  Then you code code call e.g. `foo::Log()` or `bar::Log()` to indicate which one it wants, or alternatively you could add a `using namespace foo;` declaration to tell the compiler which namespace you prefer to use by default.

Comment: How would this work when working for a company with a very large codebase? I can't imagine trying to think of a method name and then needing to double check if it already defined in some files miles away.

Edit: oh I think @JeremyFriesner just answered as soon as I pressed enter lol.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is that the linker finds it. Not the C++ compiler or program.

Comment: "Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is [used] in that program." and "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is [used]" [basic.def.odr](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#3) It's not a C++ program if there are multiple definitions